# How should I insert video in SQL Server with column of description?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables with two columns: Video and desc. I want to insert video in SQL Table. I use next script:

```
INSERT INTO table(Video)
 SELECT ( SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'source\video.mp4', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)
```

but I want also insert some description, so I imagine it like

```
INSERT INTO table(Video, desc)
 (SELECT ( SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'source\video.mp4', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x) , some_description)
```

How should I implement it?

**UPD**
What if description is the .txt file? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Do not store videos in the db, store them on File server, and store its path in the db.

Comment: `desc` is a very poor choice for a column name because it is a SQL keyword (indicating a descending sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you nesting the `select`?

```
INSERT INTO table (Video, description)
    SELECT BulkColumn, 'my description here'
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'source\video.mp4', SINGLE_BLOB) as x
```

Comment: missing description column name ;)

Comment: and what should I do if description is some .txt file?

Comment: @Nourless . . . You would pass in a valid value for whatever type it is -- either the name of the file, or a BLOB, or whatever would get inserted.